# Image-only content in a Modular Large complication?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I'm working on an Apple Watch complication and I'm only targeting **Modular Large** size. From what I can read in the Apple docs, I can only display text (and small icons, here and there).

Is there any way to display a Modular Large complication that's only comprised of a (large) image? Imagine displaying a line chart in there.

Thanks!